# How to draw TiledMap using scene2d

Tags: android, libgdx, box2d, scene2d

I want to create a tiled based game using libgdx , and I found this tutorial

[Box2d Tiled Maps](http://dpk.net/2011/05/08/libgdx-box2d-tiled-maps-full-working-example-part-1/)

The TileMapRenderer have it's own renderer to draw the tilemap. 
I want to do the tile rendering using scene2d because I am used to do things with Scene2d. also with the Stage class things like input are easier to do.
Is this tile rendering achieveable using the Actor class? can I only use the scene graph without using the spritebatch passed in the draw method on Actor class?

Answer (score 4):

No, the `TileMapRenderer` and the scene2d `Stage`/`Actor` APIs are different.  The tile map APIs do not extend or utilize the scene2d APIs.

You can use both at once in a single application (e.g., to render your game area with tiles, and your UI with scene2d).

There is a new and improved (as of Feb 2012) Libgdx Tile Map API:
http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/GraphicsTileMaps that has an [example game](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/superkoalio/SuperKoalio.java) that might help clarify things.

Comment: So what you are telling is that, you can not use a "Screen" class to render an TiledMap?

Comment: @ChuckBirkin I was talking about tile maps and the `com.badlogic.gdx.scene2d.*` packages.  `Screen` isn't part of scene2d (nor tile maps).  That said, you should be able to use a `Screen` and a tile map.

Comment: I was asking because, I haven't been able to do such. Thanks anyway

Comment: @ChuckBirkin ask a new question, include some code, and someone should be able to help!

Comment: I haven't touched Libgdx in > year, but yes there were ways to use it, but it required some hacking around. The TileMap renderer was somewhat basic. Dunno if this has been improved. But follow P.T.'s advice and post a concise question with some code you have problems with.